# How does one search for files in Elementary OS 6?

Tags: search

I need to track down some files in ES6. How can I do that. I'd like, if possible, to do a recursive search.

If Elementary OS 6 doesn't provide the feature, is there a good software package that provides the feature?

Comment: I guess it depends on what sort of file, or in which directories. Do you want to search the entire system, or just certain directories? Will you search by file name, or file contents? 

Answer (score 0):

Try [Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/) -

> Run applications, open files or their paths, open bookmarks in your
> browser, search the web, calculate things and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a folder in Files (the default file explorer in Elementary) and start typing, it will perform a deep search – however it will only search in file *names*, not their content afaik.

Alternatively, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to trigger the same functionality.